# How to get two primary keys from table as single row

Tags: sql, database

So I have a database with the following:

```
Family Name  Age  Location
Tiger  Vas   12     NA
Tiger  LA    23     NY
LAS    Vas   22     ZY
```

Family and age are primary Keys. I want to get all the rows with the primary key pair family and name. All it needs to sort alphabetically by the family then the name.
So:

```
Tiger Vas
Tiger LA
LAS VAS
```

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM Plants WHERE (Family, Name).
```

It did not work.

Comment: A table can only have one primary key. You are probably talking about a "composite PK" that -- as its name implies -- includes multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply looking for `order by`?

```
select p.*
from plants p
order by family, name;
```

Comment: It needs to bring back only the Family and Name pair, not the entire row.

Comment: Would this work? select p.Family,p.NAME FROM Plants p order by family, name;

Comment: @hecaviv546 . . . Yes.  You should select only the columns you want.